# How do I include a photo in my question?

Tags: support

I have obtained a scanned photo to include in my question as suggested. How do I include it in my question, [How do I identify the date a photo was taken or printed?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/how-do-i-identify-the-date-a-photo-was-taken-or-printed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "add media" icon is located in the toolbar just above the questions and answer boxes; it looks like a picture window. I've marked it on the image below. Click on the icon, then browse to the file image you want to upload. (There is an option to add "from the web"; I've not have experience with that option.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: No freehand circles??!

Comment: "From the web" is simply entering the url of any picture on the web. On any webpage, right-click on a picture, select "properties" and then copy the Address (Url) of the picture to the clipboard, and paste that as the url.

Comment: If you do grab something from the web, just remember to cite the source if you don't own the content. ;)